How to get an array of random values from a DataBase table via JDBC and pass them as parameters to REST API JSON messages in Jmeter?
My JSON message body will have an array of 1 or more objects and each object in the array will be populated with few attributes. I need to populate the value for one of the attributes called 'ID' by obtaining a random value from PostGresSQL Database. I have done it successfully for 1 object in the REST API Message body - by generating a random number (Jmeter random variable), passing it to DataBase using a sql query via JDBC PreProcessor sampler to get the ID. It works fine when there is only 1  object in the array but I am unsure how to pass & get more values if the array has more than 1 object. Any help/suggestion would be helpful.
Thanks,
NP
I tried for 1 object in the REST API Message body - by generating a random number (Jmeter random variable), passing it to DataBase using a sql query via JDBC PreProcessor sampler to get the ID. It works fine when there is only 1  object in the array but I am unsure how to pass & get more values if the array has more than 1 object. Any help/suggestion would be helpful.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As per JDBC Request sampler documentation if you amend your SQL query to pass 2 or more random variables so it would return return > 1 result it will generate the following JMeter Variables:
A_#=2 (number of rows)
A_1=column 1, row 1
A_2=column 1, row 2

then you can dynamically build request body using JSR223 PreProcessor, see Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON for example code in particular and Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For? article for general information on Groovy scripting in JMeter

Thanks very much, Ivan. I will try it out
